# Using JavaScript to interface with REST APIs

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, node.js, json, rest

The website [TryHackMe](https://tryhackme.com) came up with a challenge that involves using HTTP requests to interface with REST APIs ([here, task #14/day 9](https://tryhackme.com/room/25daysofchristmas)). The challenge basically involves querying a basic REST API to reconstruct a string value from the information returned by the service. Specifically, the `value` key has a piece of the string to be appended to a final string, and the `next` key has a subdirectory to visit for the next `value` to be appended to the final string. The solution is supposed to repeat this procedure until the `value` key has a value of "end".

I published a writeup that discusses this further (if the paywall is giving you problems, just open this link in private browsing ;-):

- "Aleksey" (2023). *Hacking REST APIs with JavaScript*. JavaScript In Plain English. Link: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/hacking-rest-apis-with-javascript-ecf39e38c21f

Here are some things that I am curious about:

1. What are your initial & overall impressions of the code?
2. Is there a better way of writing an implementation?
3. A bit of a rehash of the second one, but what do you **not** like about my code (assuming that you notice flaws)?
4. A bit of a meta question: do you think I can present my problem & solution a little better next time?

And of course, my JavaScript solution

```javascript
/*
 * An implementation to the Advent of Cyber's "Requests" task.
 * (Partially) ported from Hamdan (2021)'s solution
 * Implemented by Aleksey
 *  - GitHub: https://github.com/Alekseyyy
 *  - Keybase: https://keybase.io/epsiloncalculus
 */

const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "http://requests.thm:3000/";

let currentPath = "";
let flag = "";

let done = false;
while (!done) {
  if (currentPath.toLowerCase() === "end") {
    done = true;
    break;
  }

  xhr.open("GET", url + currentPath, false);
  xhr.send();

  const myJson = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  flag += myJson["value"];
  currentPath = myJson["next"];
}

console.log(flag);

/* References
 * Hamdan, M. (2021). Python For Web Automation | TryHackMe
 *   Advent Of Cyber 1 Day 9. YouTube Video. Retrieved on Feb.
 *   12, 2023 from: https://youtu.be/zFeLExZNPso
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your questions

> *"What are your initial & overall impressions of the code?"*

- Very old school, then I noticed that this must be Node.js. Is `fetch` still behind a flag??? Though a synchronous request is old school as well. When possible always use asynchronous API's
- Looks like you do not understand what JSON is! JSON is a transport format (file) when loaded and parsed JSON is an object like any other object.

  You don't need to use bracket notation when not required. `flag += myJson["value"];` is same as `flag += myJson.value;`

  You only use bracket notation if the object property has an illegal JavaScript name eg `flag += myJson["1flag"];` is valid but as `myJson.1flag` is a syntax error.
- Prefixing `my` to names is only for example code and represents a name to replace with your own variables name, you should never prefix `my` in your own code.
- Not catching errors. `JSON.parse` can throw, server requests can fail, yet there is no error checking in your code?
- `currentPath` too verbose in this context and could just be `path`

---

> *"Is there a better way of writing an implementation?"*

Yes use the `fetch` API and async functions. Node has fetch behind some flags eg `node --experimental-fetch myCode.js`

See rewrite

Note rather than `break` out of the while loop, the rewrite tests for path === "end" inside the `while` clause using a reg expression eg `while (!path.match(/^end$/i)) {`

---

> *"A bit of a meta question: do you think I can present my problem & solution a little better next time?"*

I edited your question and replaced the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag with [node](/questions/tagged/node) as it was far more relevant to the question.

### Rewrite

Rewrite uses fetch API and async function.

The catch will catch both request errors and JSON parsing errors.

```
const url = "url";
async function doThing() {
    var path = "", flag = "";    
    while (!path.match(/^end$/i)) {
        const data = await fetch(url + path).then(res => res.json());
        flag += data.value;
        path = data.next;       
    }
    return flag;
}

doThing()
    .then(flag => console.log(flag))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback. I am not a JavaScript programmer (like you noticed, I'm more "old school"), so that's probably why my code is substandard. Regarding exception handling, I knowingly did not implement it because this is more "quick and dirty." And regarding the arrow operators, I did not use them since I'm more used to the object-oriented approach (though should work more with the functional approach). But yeah, we do appreciate your advices & will try to learn more JavaScript!